# Displaying crosshairs in the center of a JavaScript Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay

I'd like to display a crosshair/reticule that's fixed in the center of a Google Map, just as [Wikimapia.org](http://wikimapia.org) do.  Unfortunately they are using v2 of the API and I'm using v3.

The crosshair should remain fixed in the center as the user pans the map around.

There's no `CENTER` option for the [ControlPosition](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ControlPosition) enum, so I imagine any solution will be a bit hacky.

I've tried to overlay it as a div outside of the map, but I haven't managed to get it to display on top of the map -- it seems to get trumped in a z-order showdown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The given solution didn't work for me, because the overlying div creates a dead spot in the map. A better solution for my project, using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3, was to create the reticle on the map as a marker with a 1 pixel rectangle shape. Then use the maps bounds_changed event to recenter the marker.

Reticle image is 63 x 63 png. (images/reticle.png)

Define the marker image and shape...

```
  var reticleImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'images/reticle.png',            // marker image
    new google.maps.Size(63, 63),    // marker size
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),      // marker origin
    new google.maps.Point(32, 32));  // marker anchor point
  var reticleShape = {
    coords: [32,32,32,32],           // 1px
    type: 'rect'                     // rectangle
  };
```

After creation of our map (main_map) we add the marker...

```
  reticleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: main_map,
    icon: reticleImage, 
    shape: reticleShape,
    optimized: false,
    zIndex: 5
  });
```

Here the var latlng is the same LatLng object used to create main_map. The zIndex should be greater than any other marker zIndex's, to keep the reticle on top.

Then we add an event handler to be called when the map bounds_changed is fired.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(main_map, 'bounds_changed', centerReticle);
```

and finally we have the centerReticle() function.

```
  function centerReticle(){
    reticleMarker.setPosition(main_map.getCenter());
  }
```

Since we're not doing anything else with the 'bounds_changed' event we can tidy up the code by passing an anonymous function to the addListener call... This keeps us from having to define the centerReticle() function.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(main_map, 'bounds_changed',
      function(){reticleMarker.setPosition(main_map.getCenter());});
```

It actually works pretty slick. I hope this helps others.

Thanks.

Skip

Comment: Fantastic, yes my solution created a dead spot that is quite annoying, albeit small.  Give me a little white to test this out...

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm glad you noticed my answer, cause it seems to be the trick. As usual I found your question while searching for the answer, but never got the overlying div away from the top left corner of the map before realizing I wasn't going to be happy with it. I'm currently working on, PithyTwits, a twitter web app. I shy away from the term geocoding because people want to make it all scientifical. I don't do geocoding, I'm just gathering LatLng's and putting them on a map. Here's a couple tweets with screenshots. - http://bit.ly/iuo9Ia http://bit.ly/iTOjeb

Comment: I just got around to trying this and it works perfectly -- no more dead spot!  Many thanks.  Wish I could vote for this twice :)

Comment: One small issue with this approach is that the marker goes a bit wonky when you zoom in and out (on Win7 Chrome anyway.)  It gets stretched during the intermediate frames of the zoom animation.  Any thoughts?  Maybe there's another event that can be hooked.

Comment: I don't know? I'm on Linux, and in Firefox it wiggles a little as you zoom/pan, but in chrome it's rock steady. I don't think there would be another event that would fire more often/reliably than change_bounds. One other quirk I did notice. I animate selected markers with bounce. When they are bouncing they aren't clickable behind the reticle. A stationary overlay still might be the preferable fix. Though I got so much to do at this point, it's gonna take a back burner. Have fun!

Comment: I took out the optimized and zIndex options. That makes it slide underneath other markers, but it solves the issue with bouncing markers hiding behind it. In this case functionality trumps display, as it should.

Comment: Just re-reading this question now and realised that the dead spot can be addressed by setting `pointer-events: none` on the reticule. Updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4130303/24874).

Answer (score 9):

Ok I'm a fool and was making this harder than it ought to be.

Rather than delete the question, here's a solution in case it helps someone else out:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="reticule"><img src="reticule.gif" /></div>
</div>
```

And some styles:

```
#container { position:relative; }
#map { height:100%; width:100%; }
#reticule {
    position:absolute;
    width:13px;
    height:13px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-8px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

That's not the exact center of the map

Comment: @gGalen, you cannot accept your own answer until two days have passed since the asking of the question.

Answer (score 8):

I am using the solution I found at [DaftLogic.com](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-centre-crosshairs.htm).  It seems to be basically the same solution as BentFX but much more terse.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: '/images/reticle.png'
});
marker.bindTo('position', map, 'center');
```

Unfortunately it also suffers from the problem Drew noted where the crosshairs are not permanently fixed to the center of the map.  If you drag the map quickly or zoom in and out, you will see the crosshairs move a little until it has time to be recentered.  If anyone comes up with a better solution, please let us know.

Comment: The marker.bindTo(); function is great. Notice in the DaftLogic.com solution that when you hover over the reticle the cursor changes, and when you drag across it, it has a dead spot. Both of these issues are overcome by defining an empty (1px rectangle) shape for the marker.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this jsfiddle which handles this gracefully, with plain css! http://jsfiddle.net/egak/X5r8r/2351/

```html
<div id="wrap1">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="cross"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrap1{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
#map-canvas{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#cross{
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
}
#cross::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```js
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
});
```

Credits to the author, http://jsfiddle.net/user/egak/